# Paypal IPN returning empty string, PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Following is my code which I am using:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->paypal_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: ' . $url_parsed['host']));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

this->paypal_url is the sandbox api url and url_parsed['host'] is the sandbox paypal host name these both are correct, but the problem I am having is on every call $res is always empty.

Before getting this code from paypal developer site I was using following code:

```
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://' . $url_parsed['host'],"443",$err_num,$err_str,30);
fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n"); 
fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n"); 
fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");
```

and failed to open socket error occurred.

Before using ssl I was using this line of code:
$fp = fsockopen($url_parsed['host'],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30);

I was getting this response:

```
Server:
 HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com
Server: BigIP
Content-Length: 0
X-Cache: MISS from proxyco.confiz.com
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from proxyco.confiz.com:3128
Via: 1.0 proxyco.confiz.com:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE21)
Connection: close
```

Please help me finding the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope following links will help you..

```
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro
```

To download sample code

```
https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623
```

IPN Listner is very useful and easy to integrate